Injectivity of a function and using Maximum Likelihood estimates
I am trying to do this question:
i) Give the parametric function $ g(\theta) $ that determines the quantile of order $ \alpha $ of the normal distribution in terms of and the corresponding quantile $ z_\alpha $ of the standard normal distribution.
ii) Find the ML estimator of $ g(\theta) $
I have managed to answer the first part alright, getting the answer $g(\theta) = z_\alpha\sigma + \mu $ where $\theta = (\mu, \sigma^2)$
When doing part two I am a little stuck. I think that I am supposed to use the fact that $\widehat{g(\theta)} = g(\hat\theta)$ if g is injective. However I don't know how to show this, in fact I'm not even sure g is injective as if we take the example $\theta_1 = (0,2^2)$, $\theta_2 = (4 , 1)$ and $z_\alpha = 4$ then we have that $g(\theta_1) = g(\theta_2)$ but that $ \theta_1 \ne \theta_2$. Am I missing something obvious here or is there another way I should be doing the question?
